# How do I fix IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I am currently programming a game and had this error thrown at me.

How do I fix it?

The Code where the **IllegalArgumentException** is appearing is in the **SpriteScreen.java**

---

**SpriteScreen.java**

```
package game.gfx;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteSheet {

    public String path;
    public int width, height;

    public int[] pixels;

    public SpriteSheet(String path) {
        BufferedImage image = null;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path)); //THIS IS LINE #18 (WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURING)!
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (image == null) {
            return;
        }

        this.path = path;
        this.width = image.getWidth();
        this.height = image.getHeight();

        pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = (pixels[i] * 0xff) / 64;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.println(pixels[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at game.gfx.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:18)
at game.Game.<init>(Game.java:24)
at game.Game.main(Game.java:130)
```

---

Comment: You're sure that resource exists?

Comment: Try a debugger. My guess is `SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path)` returned `null`.

Comment: yeah, I have a sprite_sheet.png located in the res folder, which is outside of the src folder. So I call, res/sprite_sheet.png...but throws this error.

Comment: Read the documentation for `Class.getResourceAsStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems OK. I think that the problem is the path. Are you sure that you put the right path in your input? Try to start the path with "/". For example "/resources/sprite_sheet.PNG"

Comment: That works, however, it then throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my SpriteScreen class on in this line: pixels[tilePixel++] = colors[color];

Comment: that means the index of array you try to access is negative or bigger than the size of array

Answer (score -2):

Try this hope it solves your problem:

```
   if (image.equal("")) {
     return;
  }
```

Comment: Still throws that exception.